# Writing algorithms in pseudocode in latex

Tags: algorithms

Why if I write :

```
\State \textbf{upon event $< Init >$  do}
        \For{\textbf{all $n$} $\in N$}
            \State $value[r]=0$;
        \EndFor
```

I have this output:

[image]
but I want:

[image]
How can I do it?Thankyou very much

Answer (score 4):

You can define a new block structure `\Event`...`\EndEvent` to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,algorithmicx}
\algdef{SE}[EVENT]{Event}{EndEvent}[1]{\textbf{upon event}\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}{\algorithmicend\ \textbf{event}}%
\algtext*{EndEvent}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[0]
  \Event{$< Init >$}
    \For{\textbf{all} $n \in N$}
      \State $\text{value}[r] = 0$;
    \EndFor
  \EndEvent
  \State Do something else;
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OP, see also `texdoc algorithmicx`, the utility package `algpseudocode` is built with.

Comment: `$\langle\mathit{Init}\rangle}$`

Comment: thank you very much. I added \algdef{SE}[EVENT]{Event}{EndEvent}[1]{\textbf{upon event}\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}{\algorithmicend\ \textbf{event}}%
\algtext*{EndEvent} and everything works!